# Notice: Undefined index: recurring in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-stripe-integration/includes/settings.php on line 80 />

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I am getting this error on backend while setting up stripe plugin using php api library v 4.2.0.
Notice: Undefined index: recurring in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-stripe-integration/includes/settings.php on line 80 /> Check this to allow users to setup recurring payments.
[image]

My settings.php code for recurring is

```
<table class="form-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr valign="top">   
                    <th scope="row" valign="top">
                        <?php _e('Allow Recurring', 'pippin_stripe'); ?>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="stripe_settings[recurring]" name="stripe_settings[recurring]" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php checked($stripe_options['recurring'], 1); ?>/>
                        <label class="description" for="stripe_settings[recurring]"><?php _e('Check this to allow users to setup recurring payments.', 'pippin_stripe'); ?></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

and my shortcode.php code is

```
<?php if(isset($stripe_options['recurring'])) { ?>
        <div class="form-row">
            <label><?php _e('Payment Type:', 'pippin_stripe'); ?></label>
            <input type="radio" name="recurring" value="no" checked="checked"/><span><?php _e('One time payment', 'pippin_stripe'); ?></span>
            <input type="radio" name="recurring" value="yes"/><span><?php _e('Recurring monthly payment', 'pippin_stripe'); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

The radio buttons should be visible on the checkout page which are not. I am beginner in php so any help will be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am using this tutorial https://pippinsplugins.com/stripe-integration-part-2-recurring-payments/

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not an error, but just a notice. It will not terminate your code. You have probably told the server that you want to see all errors, warnings and notices.

> Offtopic: You can disable them with
>   error_reporting(0);
>   ini_set('display_errors', 0);

The notice says everything - you don't have index called "recurring" in the array variable $stripe_options. This sample of settings.php will remove the notice.

```html
<table class="form-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr valign="top">   
                    <th scope="row" valign="top">
                        <?php _e('Allow Recurring', 'pippin_stripe'); ?>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="stripe_settings[recurring]" name="stripe_settings[recurring]" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if(isset($stripe_options['recurring'])) { checked($stripe_options['recurring'], 1); } ?>/>
                        <label class="description" for="stripe_settings[recurring]"><?php _e('Check this to allow users to setup recurring payments.', 'pippin_stripe'); ?></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
```

Anyways, it is a good practice to check if the key is set with isset($array['key'])

Comment: Thanks Vachev i now realize that the notice is gone by checking it and saving it.

Comment: Sure, the $stripe_settings[recurring] is sent only if the checkbox is checked. Only then $stripe_settings[recurring] is set in settings.php. Anyways check with isset() first to make sure that you're not passing undefined to your function checked()